# Remove ItemStack from a player

Tags: java, minecraft

how are you, good morning, I'm sorry for the inconvenience, someone would be so kind to help me figure out why I can't remove an item by right clicking?

Sorry to bother you.

```
@EventHandler
public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    Player p = (Player) e.getPlayer();
    ItemStack m = new ItemStack(Material.GOLD_NUGGET, 1);
    if (e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR)) {
        if (e.getPlayer().getItemInHand().getType().equals(m)){
            p.getInventory().removeItem(m);
                p.sendMessage("-1");
        }else {
                 p.sendMessage("error");
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're comparing an `ItemStack` to a `Material`

Comment: When asking about errors you should provide enough information, e.g. what error messages you get, what you expect to happen, what happens instead, any stacktraces, what you already did to diagonose the problem etc. - if you just ask "why can't I do X?" then the answer sometimes can only be "because you did something wrong" but what exactly is hard to tell without the needed information.

Answer (score 0):

`if (e.getPlayer().getItemInHand().getType().equals(m)){`

This line is causing your code not to work, change it to:

`if (e.getPlayer().getItemInHand().getType().equals(m.getType())){`

Also you will come across another error, if you remove the last of an item from a player's inventory the entire server will crash. You have to cancel the event before removing anything.